# Optional hairstlyle with video link

Tags: python, random

I am trying to create a random hairstyle generator that gives a hairstyle and gives a certain link to a tutorial to create the following hairstyle given by the generator. Although the code does give different hairstyles I can't get the code to give a different hairstyle with the assigned link to it. Instead, it just keeps outputting the same link given at the beginning of the code.

```
import random

a = "slicked back bun"
b = "puff"
c = "bantu knots"
d = "wash n go"
e = "mini twists"
f = "braid out"
g = "twist out"
h = "half up, half down"
i = "flat twists"
j = "perm rod set"
k = "flexi rod set"
l = "cornrows"
m = "space buns"
n = "finger coils"
o = "curly mohawk"
p = "afro"
q = "sleek high bun"
r = "two braids & low ponytail"
s = "halo braid"
t = "head wrap"

mylist = [a, b, c, d, e,f, g, h, i, j, k , l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, 
          t]


def example():
    print (random.choice(mylist))
    if "puff" in mylist:
        print("https://www.youtube.com/")
    else:
        print("no hairstyle today")

def example2():
    raw_input("> ")


def example2():
    raw_input("> ")

example()
```

Comment: Please note: Python2 is end-of-life. You should upgrade to Python3

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue should be fixed hairstlyles are stored in list rather than as variables in a list, youtube link is appened with the random hairstyle.

```
import random
hairstyles = ["slicked+back+bun","puff","bantu+knots","wash+n+go","mini+twists","braid+out","twist+out","half+up,+half+down","flat+twists","perm+rod+set","flexi+rod+set","cornrows","space+buns","finger+coils","curly+mohawk","afro","sleek+high+bun","two+braids+&+low+ponytail","halo+braid","head+wrap"]

def example():
    randomStyle=random.choice(hairstyles)
    print("https://youtube.com/results?search_query="+randomStyle)
example()
```